# QueryDSL and date diff

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to compute user age with a date difference using QueryDSL.

```
QPlayer $ = QPlayer.player;
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(Expressions.dateOperation(Integer.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.DIFF_YEARS, Expressions.currentDate(), $.birthDate).between(3, 5));
playerRespository.findAll(builder);
```

But fail with this error

```
Hibernate: select player0_.user_id as id1_31_, player0_1_.user_birthdate as user_bir2_31_, player0_1_.user_register_date as user_reg3_31_, player0_1_.user_delete_date as user_del4_31_, player0_1_.user_email as user_ema5_31_, player0_1_.user_first_name as user_fir6_31_, player0_1_.user_last_name as user_las7_31_, player0_1_.user_login as user_log8_31_, player0_1_.user_password as user_pas9_31_, player0_1_.user_status as user_st10_31_, player0_.player_description as player_d1_20_, player0_.player_height as player_h2_20_, player0_.player_picture as player_p3_20_, player0_.player_role as player_r4_20_, player0_.player_weight as player_w5_20_ from players player0_ inner join users player0_1_ on player0_.user_id=player0_1_.id where (diff_years(player0_1_.user_birthdate, current_date) between ? and ?) and (lower(player0_1_.user_first_name) like ? escape '!')
2015-07-19 14:22:16,881 [main] ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - FUNCTION xxx.diff_years does not exist
```

This errors occurs using both MYSQL database or HSQL.

What's wrong with that code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

diff_years is unfortunately not yet supported in Querydsl JPA

Answer (score 1):

How to customize MYSQL dialect with queryDsl. I show how to use datediff for select statement.

Custom query request (calculate difference between now and createdDate):

```
public List<MyDto> get() {
        JPAQuery<HotelShortDto> query = new JPAQuery<>(em, MySQLJPQLTemplates.DEFAULT)
                .select(Projections.constructor(MyDto.class,
                        Expressions.dateOperation(Integer.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.DIFF_MINUTES, Expressions.currentDate(), myEntity.createdDate),
                ))
                .from(myEntity)
        return query.fetch();

}
```

In MYSQL function to get difference in minutes is TIMESTAMPDIFF (for H2 db datediff)

Configuration:

```
public class MySQLJPQLTemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public static final MySQLJPQLTemplates DEFAULT = new MySQLJPQLTemplates();

    public MySQLJPQLTemplates() {
        this(DEFAULT_ESCAPE);
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.DIFF_MINUTES, "TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,{0},{1})");
    }

    public void reconfigureForH2() {
        add(Ops.DateTimeOps.DIFF_MINUTES, "datediff(MINUTE,{0},{1})");
    }

    public MySQLJPQLTemplates(char escape) {
        super(escape);
    }
}
```

Also TIMESTAMPDIFF is not standart function for hibernate, so registration is needed

```
public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL57Dialect {

    public CustomMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("TIMESTAMPDIFF", new StandardSQLFunction("TIMESTAMPDIFF"));
    }

}
```

and application.yaml

```
...
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.my.project.CustomMySQLDialect
...
```

For testing call before execute query

```
MySQLJPQLTemplates.DEFAULT.reconfigureForH2();
```